# Fail getting readings from Radar sensor HW-MS03

Tags: sensors

I try to work with a new sensor - HW-MS03 v.06 sensor. Connecting it pin to pin (**v+** to **5v**, **Sig** to digital-input, and **GND** to **GND** ), both to Arduino Uno and ESP8266 Wemos mini, and got same results:

Only once on every port I got proper readings ( `1` for detection for 2 sec, and `0` for no- detection). Most of the time it was a solid `1`.

Code was very simple , just printing its `digitalRead` of the designated pin.

When tried to pull-down the signal, using a 1K resistor, It never got `1` again.

To be sure it is not a malfunctioned sensor I tried with the other one I have, but again- same results.

[link to purchased product](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32957025450.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dyE4ZZK)
Appreciate any help.

Guy

Comment: Wow, that is some quality documentation: "Recommended qualified power supply, ie output voltage, current and ripple factor are standard power supplies, otherwise it is a movie" And the specifications link doesn't provide any info about voltage or current requirements. I think you're on your own figuring that one out.

Comment: "it is a movie....." this is the best spec I've encountered

Comment: What do you suppose the writer is trying to say? It was word salad to me.